# Задача о расстановки королей на шахматной доске

Tags: prolog

Вообщем есть задача о расстановки королей, чтоб никто не бил друг друга. Аналог знаменитой о 8 ферзях.
Я вроде сделал, но думаю, что-то не так с поиском.
Список из 16 элементов, потому, что максимум по расстановке, чтоб они не били друг друга - 16.
Проблема с nokill. Оно реализовано как для задачи о 8 ферзях, а нужно как для королей. 
Помогите реализовать как для королей, а то ни единой идеи как это сделать.

```
    % представляем состояние в виде списка из 16 элементов, который соответствует каждому королю
getSolution(S):-
    S=[1-_,2-_,3-_,4-_,5-_,6-_,7-_,8-_,9-_,10-_,11-_,12-_,13-_,14-_,15-_,16-_],
    solution(S).

% в начальном состоянии доска не содержит ни одного короля
solution([]).

% доска NxN является решением, если является решением её под-доска (N-1)*(N-1), 
% а первый король не бьет королей на этой под-доске.
solution([X-Y | T]) :-
    solution(T),
    member(Y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]),
    nokill(X-Y, T).

% понятно что король с любыми координатами не бьет королей из пустого массива
nokill(_, []).        

% король не бьет набор королей если он не бьет первого короля из набора 
% и не бьет остальных королей набора         
nokill(X-Y, [X1-Y1 | T]) :-
    Y \= Y1,   % на разных горизонталях   
    X \= X1,
    Y1-Y =\= X1-X, % на разных диагоналях
    Y1-Y =\= X-X1,
    nokill(X-Y, T).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Король не бьёт другого, если

```
abs(x2-x1) > 1 or abs(y2-y1) > 1
```

Comment: Что-то не так с вашим решением...
И "or" нет в синтаксисе пролога.

Comment: А я синтаксиса пролога и не знаю. У Вас же не было идей - какое отличие будет от задачи с ферзями - вот оно, вместо горизонталей/диагоналей

Comment: Вы гений! По-моему это решило проблему. Правда перестановок много не делает. Все ограничивается изменением 1 короля.
Вот пример вывода: 
[1-4,2-1,3-3,4-1,5-3,6-1,7-3,8-1,9-3,10-1,11-3,12-1,13-3,14-1,15-3,16-1]
[1-5,2-1,3-3,4-1,5-3,6-1,7-3,8-1,9-3,10-1,11-3,12-1,13-3,14-1,15-3,16-1]
[1-5,2-1,3-3,4-1,5-3,6-1,7-3,8-1,9-3,10-1,11-3,12-1,13-3,14-1,15-3,16-1]
[1-5,2-1,3-3,4-1,5-3,6-1,7-3,8-1,9-3,10-1,11-3,12-1,13-3,14-1,15-3,16-1]
[1-5,2-1,3-3,4-1,5-3,6-1,7-3,8-1,9-3,10-1,11-3,12-1,13-3,14-1,15-3,16-1]

Comment: Я так подозреваю, что проблема с тем, что просто превышает лимит аутпута, вот и все.